# Netsuite bundle installation stays in Pending forever

Tags: bundle, netsuite

I have NetSuite (Edition: United States) Release 2018.2

I created a bundle to lock down modifications of some previously created custom fields (about 30 fields in the bundle). I pressed Install button and installation seems hanged. It's been staying in Pending... state for several days.

Can I check somewhere the reason the bundle hasn't been installed?

If I uninstall the bundle in Pending... state, will it delete previously created custom fields? (I'd want them to stay)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those fields were created by another bundle, then uninstalling the new bundle won't delete them. If they were created directly in the account, it won't be a problem too.

Is there any place to check ? : no, this kind of delay happens sometimes, mostly in dev and sandbox accounts and you have three options:

1. Wait : at the end, it will be a success or an error : if it is an error, when you pass the cursor on the "error", you will get "some" details. You said, several days, then probably it is best to try next options.
2. Ignore the "pending" message, and re-install: this can make things move a little bit.
3. Contact Netsuite support.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that bundle unistallation doesn't spoil anything. I also found that there was a possibility to Dissolve the bundle. Thanks for the rapid answer!